# Updating excel file using ODBC and PHP

Tags: php, excel, odbc

I am using an Excel file as a database and connecting to this file using ODBC drivers with PHP.

While updating a particular field, the updated value gets formatted as text. I am updating a number value but in Excel the value gets formatted as a text.

I want this updated value as a number formatted to run my formulas in Excel.